# Trying to set the react DatePickers initial date using the users timezone is throwing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a React project, and I am trying to set the DatePickers default date when it loads to the users timezone which is given to me by the API. Every time i try and inject the date it throws an error.

Below is the code which renders the datepicker fine;

```
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker'
import 'react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'
import { formatInTimeZone } from 'date-fns-tz'


const Dates = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name='end_time'
                defaultValue={new Date()}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        onChange={onChange}
                        value={value ? new Date(value) : null}
                        format="dd-MM-y h:mm a"
                    />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dates
```

But then when i change the `defaultValue` line to feed in the users timezone like so;

```
defaultValue={formatInTimeZone(new Date(), user.timezone)}
```

I get the following error;

```
RangeError: Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `n`
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a similar case of your problem in this [issue of date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1857#issuecomment-807272204), think it could help.

In short, it seems that your `user.timezone` is having a value of `null` or `undefined` that caused the problem. I can't affirm for sure what the root of the problem is, since you haven't provide any information about that variable. But I hope this helps.